# Is there any way to inject text onto pages?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, text

I run a network of sites that get updated constantly, and the content they cover is updated frequently itself.

So on each page we have a "updated for [text we want injected]"

Is there a way to edit this text in just one place, so that it updates everywhere across the site? Instead of manually having to edit thousands of pages?

Comment: how about in the template?

Comment: In order to receive an adequate answer catering to *exactly your problem* you will have to disclose the nature of `[text we want injected]` - is that a static string? Is it dynamic content? If so, what does it depend on - user input, time/date, post ID?

Comment: It'd be something we input ourselves. It's not a date or time, It's closest to being a version number that we're updating for.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate option that will be called in the template. And i would make an options page also.

Here is a [TUTORIAL](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/) i followed and succeeded in creating my options pages for multiple themes .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is. Asuming that `text we want injected` for each post may be different, then you must use [Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)!

Create the field `post_updated_for` for posts you need to. Then edit your template to display that field. Check the [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of ways, settings, transient, ecc..

1 minute solution?

Do you have a home page, I think, if not choose a page you like.

Add a custom field 'updated_for' and set here what you want.

After that in `functions.php` add:

```
function updated_for( $content ) {
  if ( ! is_singular() || is_front_page() ) return;
  $page = get_page_by_title('Home Page'); // change the title with the page you choose
  if ( ! empty($page) ) {
    $upd = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'updated_for', true );
    $content .= '<p class="updated-for">' __('Updated for: ') . $upd. '<p>';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'updated_for', 9999);
```